# Displaying Toast message from user defined variable

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

How do I pass a user variable as a parameter in the Toast object in android studio to display the value of the variable?

Something like this;

Toast.makeText(userVariable,R.id.textField,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getViewById() to get the Text input as a View, cast it to a TextInputView and then once you've done that, you can call getText().toString() and pass this into the toast.